# RavenDb, how can I query properties of T in a 'List<T>' which itself is a property of an object stored in Ravendb?

Tags: c#, ravendb, document-database

RavenDb, how can I query properties of T in a List of 'Ts' which itself is a property of an object stored in Ravendb?

my question is will RavenB load the complete object which contains the list into memory in order to query properties of objects contained in such list? My point is that this list may contain a million elements and I only want to select a few through a linq query? Can such query be executed on the server side or will the object, containing the list, be loaded into the client side memory in its entirety just to query its properties?

Comment: It's important that you're *not* dealing with lists, you (should be) dealing with objects of type `IQueryable<T>` rather than `List<T>`.  Because of that, it can be doing all of the work in the DB and not pull any more than it absolutely needs to over to your application.

Comment: @Servy, would you have some code sample or reference that touches on my problem? I need to store a large collection of Ts and want to query them to only return a subset or properties of such subset.

Comment: Please show a sample query and the actual structure of your objects